# Firebase Notification issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to access the title and body of a firebase notification when user click on the notification using Android?

I easily pass a notification message to specific user but I want access message variable at other end for other purpose. what should I do, please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `onMessageReceived()` to get the `notification` and to access its properties like `title` and `body`, like below:

```
class CustomFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val notificationTitle = remoteMessage.notification?.title
        val notificationBody = remoteMessage.notification?.body
    }
```